# GPU PowerVR SGX 544MP3 black screen when rendering shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpu, powervr-sgx

I'm working with OpenGL on Samsung Galaxi S4, its GPU is PowerVR SGX 544MP3 and I'm having some king of native error when I'm trying to apply a shader:

```
01-09 09:28:27.221: E/IMGSRV(28967): :0: DestroyPDSVariantGhostKRM: Shouldn't be called ever
```

I've been looking for that error message on google with null results, also - I didn't published my code because its quite strait forward and have been tested on hundred of devices.

Comment: Even if your code is really straightforward and tested you really should post it here. I'd like to take a look at both vertex and fragment shaders. Do you check GL errors on each state of shader creation? Are there any errors on compilation/linking?

Comment: @keaukraine I'll add the relevant code to the body of the question, and no there wasn't any GL errors or linking error, nothing..